# Facebook login button just won't show up

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-login

I went to this page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button

I copied and pasted the code they give, in my HTML index:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

(that's right after the body tag, as they recommend), and then :

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="icon" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```

anywhere in the page, it doesn't work. The button does not show up. If I add a red border to it, a vertical red line appears, showing that the button doesn't render.

I have tried with different options, locally, on my server, and in a codepen (http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/EWWRdy?editors=1100), no avail.

No error in the console, no problem in the network tab. "sdk.js" is found and loaded.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: As I said, no, no errors.

Comment: do you have a test link for us?

Comment: I do, it's in the question (codepen)

Comment: do `console.log(d.getElementById(id))` after the first row in your script, what does it return?

Comment: Codepen throws error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': Assignment is forbidden for sandboxed iframes.
    at https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/ao6eUeuGXQq.js?version=42:1:118`

Comment: Where do you insert the Facebook-Script ?

Comment: console.log(d.getElementById(id)) after the first row in your script --> it returns null, which makes sense, because that element hasn't been created yet. You're testing "#facebook-jssdk" but it's being created two lines below that.

Comment: Where do you insert the Facebook-Script ? --> As I said, right after the body tag. Three questions in the comments, the three answers are in my original question :)

Comment: You need to initialize that facebook sdk first. See this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Comment: Codepen throws error --> Hmmm, you're right, because it's a sandbox. But I get no errors locally and on my server, and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: You need to initialize that facebook sdk first --> Wow, that is interesting. They don't talk about that whatsoever on the login button page. I'll try that and I'll get back, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize the facebook sdk first. See this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart